# xsd: choice groups of attributes

Tags: xml, xsd

what i made wrong? 
xls:

```
 <note>
  <element action="SomeAction" id="1" />
 </note>
```

xsd:

```
    <xs:element name="note">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:choice minOccurs ="0">
            <xs:group ref="with_attr" />
            <xs:group ref ="without_attr" />
          </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:group name="with_attr">
        <xs:sequence >
          <xs:element name="element">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:attributeGroup ref="actionattrib" />
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:group>
      <xs:group name="without_attr">
        <xs:sequence >
          <xs:element name="element">
            <xs:complexType>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:group>
  <xs:attributeGroup name ="actionattrib">
    <xs:attribute name="action" type="action_value" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="parameter" type="id_value" use="required"/>
  </xs:attributeGroup>
      <xs:simpleType name="action_value" >
        <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
          <xs:enumeration value="SomeAction"/>
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
      <xs:simpleType name="id_value" >
        <xs:restriction base="xs:token">"
          <xs:enumeration value="1"/>
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
```

i try to make rule that element `note` can contains  element `<element>` with attributes `action` and `id` that will be have value from list, or `element` without any attributes will be correct too, but `element` cant contain other attributes or only one of  attributes `id` or `action`. 
Error is : Attribute `action` is not allowed here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct XML is ... I validatied below XML by [XMLSpear](http://www.donkeydevelopment.com/)

```
<note>
    <element action="SomeAction" parameter="1"/>
</note>
```

If you want use your XML, you should change the XSD in ..

```
<xs:attributeGroup name ="actionattrib">
   <xs:attribute name="action" type="action_value" use="required"/>
   <xs:attribute name="id" type="id_value" use="required"/>
</xs:attributeGroup>
```

---

I used this XSD to validate the XML.

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >
    <xs:element name="note">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0">
                <xs:group ref="with_attr"/>
                <xs:group ref="without_attr"/>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:group name="with_attr">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="element">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:attributeGroup ref="actionattrib"/>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:group>
    <xs:group name="without_attr">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="element">
                <xs:complexType>
            </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:group>
    <xs:attributeGroup name="actionattrib">
        <xs:attribute name="action" type="action_value" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="parameter" type="id_value" use="required"/>
    </xs:attributeGroup>
    <xs:simpleType name="action_value">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
            <xs:enumeration value="SomeAction"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="id_value">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
          <xs:enumeration value="1"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

Your problem is on attribute `id` of tag `<element>`, because you've declared as parameter.

Comment: so it is problem with Namespace?

Comment: id is ok, i make mistake when i write here, but problem that i cant change xml file, only  header. i use rubymine for see errors, and it still show me it,can you write and a full xsd (with header) maybe problem is there..

Comment: will you be so kind to contact me by skype, i will show you all code, and maybe i'll help you in future if you will  need my help

Comment: The code in this post, unfortunately, won't work. Though it is known that some (older) XSD parsers may accept it, most, if not all, will throw a "Unique Particle Attribution" ambiguity error, because the resulting schema is ambiguous (two elements with the same name, but different attribute groups, at the same choice level).